# Is there any way of caching dependencies in a grails application ((Packaging Grails application) in order to speed up tests?

Tags: groovy, grails

Is there any way of cache dependencies in a grails application to speed up tests and prevent packaging grails application everytime I run `grails test-app`command?

I'm using a docker container as well.
I want to speed up my test process, everytime I run the tests with `grails test-app` it reload the entire environment and it takes a lot of time.
This are the logs that prints:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.5
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to test
| Environment set to test.
| Environment set to test..
| Environment set to test...
| Environment set to test....
| Environment set to test.....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
```

The stuff that takes more time it's packaging grails application.
And I'm using grails 2.1.5

I've tried commenting dependencies, plugins or repos in the BuildConfig.groovy, modifying the scopes of the dependencies 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided'.
But with no luck.